# Mounting old Paragon PBF image file, does not show up in archive manager?

Tags: backup, paragon

I have an old Paragon Backup file, from which I would like to retrive some files.
The file is a PBF file and some .0000, .0001 archive files.
It apparently was created with Paragon version 9.

I installed this in a Windows XP virtual machine and tried to mount the PBF or to add them.
But I was unsuccessful, the files do not show up in the list of archives.

I then created a new backup, I got a PFI file, which is apparently the newer version.
This shows up in the Archive list in Paragon, but not the old PBF file.

How can I mount this PBF file?

Comment: Have you confirmed the current version of the Paragon program does not mount these files?  You might have to change the file extension filter when offered a list of files to mount, but it should work, if the current version does not support it only running the a previous version will allow you to acomplish your goals.

Comment: Well, version 16 appears to be unable to mount it. Version 15 appears to have some sort of legacy support, but I was unable to mount it too in there. I do not know why it does not show up in version 9, as this is about 2009?

Comment: Contact Paragon customer support for your options.  The dangers of using a format, created by Paragon, is they can discontinue supporting that format.